# Sources in unimodular rows

Tags: reference-request

I'm beginning to study more advanced material of module theory and I need to study more about unimodular rows. I would like a good introductory book or pdf speaking about unimodular rows with theorems, proofs and examples in this level:

> $P(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is free iff $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ is the first line
>   of an invertible matrix

Another example:

> $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\alpha$ is unimodular if $a$ is an invertible
>   matrix.

Anyone knows where can I find such a book (or pdf)? I've found only some books which doesn't speak very long about this subject specifically such as [Serre's Problem on Projective modules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540233172).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the discussion at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/primvector.pdf would help out a little.

Comment: You could start with Bass's book on Algebraic K-theory.  You can also work through the many papers of people like Vaserstein and Suslin that make heavy use of unimodular rows.  There's a paper by Swan and Towber called "A Class of Projective Modules That Are Nearly Free" that has some nice simple applications of these ideas, and would surely help to give you the flavor of the subject.